# Theorem of sign permanence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

From the Theorem of sign permanence I can say that if eventually $a<a_n<b$ then $a\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\leq b$?

Comment: Yes. You don't even need any theorem, just observe that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n>b$ then for $n$ large enough $a_n>b$, a contradiction.